# PHP cookies in a session handler

Tags: php, cookies, session

I have run into a very interesting problem trying to debug my custom PHP session handler. For some reason unknown to me I can set cookies all the way through the session handler right up until the very start of the write function.

As far as I know session handler calls go in this order.

```
open -> read -> write -> close
```

The open function sets a cookie just fine.

```
function open($save_path,$session_name)  
{  
  require_once('database.php');  
  require_once('websiteinfo.php');
  mysql_connect($sqllocation,$sql_session_user,$sql_session_pass);
  @mysql_select_db($sql_default_db);
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');  
  setcookie("test","test");
  return TRUE;  
}
```

The read function can set a cookie right up until the very moment it returns a value.

```
function read($session_id)
{
  $time = time();
  $query = "SELECT * FROM 'sessions' WHERE 'expires' > '$time'";
  $query_result = mysql_query($query);
  $data = '';

  /* fetch the array and start sifting through it */
  while($session_array = mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
  {
    /* strip the slashes from the session array */
    $session_array = $this->strip($session_array);

    /* authenticate the user and if so return the session data */
    if($this->auth_check($session_array,$session_id))
    {
      $data = $session_array['data'];
    }
  }

  setcookie("testcookie1","value1",time()+1000,'/');

  return $data;
}
```

The very first line of the write function is setting another cookie and it cannot because the headers are already sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual for [session_set_save_handler()](http://php.net/session_set_save_handler):

> Note: The "write" handler is not
>   executed until after the output stream
>   is closed. Thus, output from debugging
>   statements in the "write" handler will
>   never be seen in the browser. If
>   debugging output is necessary, it is
>   suggested that the debug output be
>   written to a file instead.

Essentially, writing changes to session data (calling the registered session write function) does not happen until PHP is almost completely done with its execution cycle.  By this time, all your output has already been sent and it is not possible to modify the header information, so `setcookie()` won't work.

You can have it write data earlier by using [session_write_close()](http://php.net/function.session-write-close).

Comment: I do believe that is the answer to my problem good sir. thank you very much.